# Debugging a plugin in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, plugins, visual-studio-debugging

I have a configuration tool application which uses a custom written plugin called "PluginInterface.dll", which using the config tool I noticed a bug which I traced back to the plugin.

I would really like to be able to debug this to pinpoint the error but I've been unable to find out how to do this. I first tried attaching the debugger to the process (didn't really expect that to work) then I had a search around.

Very few results, I've followed this guide which describes how to have VS launch an external application when it starts to debug but I just got the standard "Cannot run a class library error".
http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/4209-how-to-debug-your-plugin/

Comment: Attaching to the VS process hosting the plugin not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the symbols for the PluginInterface.dll assembly. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41.aspx) for information on doing this. This should allow you to step into the code from that assembly (and set breakpoints in its code files) as though it were inside your current assembly.